# Lexicographic order, strings, c++

Tags: c++, string, char, std

I have a problem with my next task. The problem is :

> Let's assume we've got an alphabet A (c,a,b). Write function :
>
> ```
> int my_strcmp(char S1[], char S2[]);
> ```
>
> which will compare char arrays S1 and S2, written in A alhpabet.
>   Outcome should be :
>
> > `0`, if S1==S2
> >     `-1`, if S1 is lexicographically smaller than S2
> >     `+1`, if S1 is lexicographically larger than S2

Test-cases:

"`aa`" "`cc`" => 1
"`ac`" "`a`" => 1
"`c`"  "`ac`" => -1
"`bc`" "`ab`" => 1
"`bc`" "`ac`" => 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

#define T_SIZE 1001

int my_strcmp(char S1[], char S2[]);
int compCh(char a, char b);

int main(){
  int t; 
  char S1[T_SIZE], S2[T_SIZE];
  scanf_s("%d", &t);

  while(t) { 

    std::cin.getline(S1,T_SIZE,' ');
    std::cin.getline(S2, T_SIZE);
    printf("%d\n", my_strcmp(S1, S2));

    t--;   
  } 
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

int compCh(char a, char b) {
    int x, y;
    switch (a) {
    case 'c':
        x = 0;
        break;
    case 'a':
        x = 1;
        break;
    default:
        x = 2;
        break;
    }
    switch (b) {
    case 'c':
        y = 0;
        break;
    case 'a':
        y = 1;
        break;
    default:
        y = 2;
        break;
    }
    return (x - y);
}

int my_strcmp(char S1[], char S2[]) {

    for (int i = 0; (i<std::min(strlen(S1), strlen(S2))); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            if (compCh(S1[i+1], S2[i]) == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            else if (compCh(S1[i+1], S2[i]) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (compCh(S1[i], S2[i]) == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            else if (compCh(S1[i], S2[i]) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (strlen(S1) > strlen(S2)) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I don't know why is it now working. I figured out that when in

> my_strcmp

function i==0, then S1[i] will be equal to some weird unseen symbol. Even tho, after changing the function with if statement, to catch if i==0, program is still not working. I have no idea, where the mistake was made, since this program is being checked by an online judge program.

I'm not asking for ready answer, but please just point me to the mistake I'm making.

Comment: Are you sure the longer string should compare as smaller when one is the prefix of the other?

Comment: Run your program in a debugger, and step through the code line by line to see what it's really doing.

Comment: Corrected this to i==0. For some reason even if S1 = "a", then it is possible for me to get S1[1], which will be equal to "a". It is only doable in first run of for loop. The next ones seems to work fine.

Comment: Why are you comparing characters at different indices `compCh(S1[i+1], S2[i])`? And what's the whole point of `if (i == 0)`? Also you never return `0` if strings are equal.

Comment: I'm comparing them, cause on first run of for loop, for some unknown reason S[i+1] is equal to the first character of an array. With the return 0 part - thanks, will correct this.

Comment: @Setzo What to do if a charater will be encountered that does not equal tp one of "bca"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take into account that there is no need to use function `compCh` that to determine whether two characters are equal. Thus binstead of

```
if (compCh(S1[i], S2[i]) == 0) {
```

you could write simply

```
if ( S1[i] == S2[i] ) {
```

Also after the loop you have to check whether the two strings are equal. Also it is not clear what you are trying to do when i is equal to 0.

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>

int weight( char c )
{
    const char order[] = "cab";
    const int N = 3;
    int n = 0;

    while ( n < N && order[n] != c ) ++n;

    return n == N ? 0 : ++n;
}

int my_strcmp( const char s1[], const char s2[] ) 
{
    while ( *s1 && *s1 == *s2 ) ++s1, ++s2;

    return *s1 == *s2 ? 0 : ( weight( *s1 ) < weight( *s2 ) ? - 1 : 1 );
}

int main()
{
    for ( auto p : { std::make_pair( "aa", "cc" ), 
                     std::make_pair( "ac", "a" ),
                     std::make_pair( "c", "ac" ),
                     std::make_pair( "bc", "ab" ),
                     std::make_pair( "bc", "ac" ),
                   } )
    {
        std::cout << "\"" << std::setw( 2 ) << p.first
                  << "\" \"" << std::setw( 2 ) << p.second
                  << "\" => " << my_strcmp( p.first, p.second )
                  << std::endl;
    }                  

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"aa" "cc" => 1
"ac" " a" => 1
" c" "ac" => -1
"bc" "ab" => 1
"bc" "ac" => 1
```

As you can see the functions are very simple and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code by encapsulating repeating code:

```
static inline char map_alpha(char x) {
    switch(x) {
    case 'a': return 'b';
    case 'b': return 'c';
    case 'c': return 'a';
    case 0: return '\xFF'; // A shorter string is bigger [!]
    case '\xFF': return 0; // "
    }
    return x;
}
```

And now use it in the prototypical string-compare-function:

```
// Added const, because the function never changes its inputs
int compare_mapped(const char* a, const char* b) {
    while(*a && *a == *b) // No need to map here, its bijective
        ++a, ++b;
    int r = 0 + (unsigned char)map_alpha(*a) - (unsigned char)map_alpha(*b);
    // cast to unsigned char, because char might be signed
    return r < 0 ? -1 : !!r; // normalize return, though that's curious.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be a fairly simple algorithm once you've written the comparison.

Your bug is just that you do `compCh(S1[i`**`+ 1`**`], S2[i]) == 0) {`

That `+ 1` needs to be removed then everything should work fine.

That said, your `my_strcmp` seems a bit unnecessarily complex. I've written a simplified version of `my_strcmp` below which still uses `compCh`:

> `int my_strcmp(char S1[], char S2[]){`
>  `const int S1size = strlen(S1);`
>  `const int S2size = strlen(S2);`
>  `const auto size = std::min(S1size, S2size);`
>  `const auto S1end = std::next(S1, size);`
>  `const auto result = std::mismatch(S1, S1end, S2);`
>
>  `return result.first == S1end ? std::min(1, std::max(-1, S1size - S2size)) : compCh(*result.first, *result.second);`
>  `}`
>
>  If you're using Visual Studio to compile this you'll get an error unless you use a `stdext::checked_array_iterator` on the last parameter of `std::mismatch`. Using this line instead will solve it: `const auto result = std::mismatch(S1, S1end, stdext::checked_array_iterator<char*>(S2, size));`

A few other things to be aware of:

1. You should verify in your comparison or somewhere before that the strings conform to your three letter alphabet.
2. You need to handle whitespace.
3. You need to handle capital letters, or `lcase` everything before running `my_strcmp`.